# Creating 2 Exceptions in a Finally Block

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code:

```
finally
{
    if (!isDnsSet)
    {
        var exception = new Exception(<DNS-INFORMATION>);
                        localLog.TraceException(exception);
                        throw exception;
    }
}
```

As it stands, this exception throws too much information to the user that is not particularly needed for them to see. I want to be able to log `exception` using my `localLog` class but also throw another exception with a more concise message.

I was thinking to just create another exception with the shortened message and still log the original, more verbose one using my class.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this or would I just do something like:

```
var shortException = new Exception(<short and sweet message>);
var longException = new Exception(<not so short and sweet but still useful for other devs>);
localLog.TraceException(longException);
throw shortException;
```

Comment: If you want to log one exception and throw another this is probably as terse as you can get.  I have to say I'm not crazy about the idea of redacting the exception when throwing - seems like that decision should be done higher up the stack, or diagnosing problems could be difficult.

Comment: only I think of idea throwing exception from the finally - not catch block little strange ?

Comment: This is a complete method with a `try->catch->finally`. I've just decided to leave that part out

Comment: Have you considered making the "longException" the innerException in the "shortException"? I'm not sure it's actually more elegant, but it might allow you to log and throw the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a cleaner method would be to make the longer exception an *inner* exception:

```
finally
{
    if (!isDnsSet)
    {
        var innerException = new Exception(<not so short and sweet but still useful for other devs>);
        var exception = new Exception(<short and sweet message>, innerException);
        localLog.TraceException(exception);
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

That way you have consistency between the exception that's thrown and the exception that's logged, making diagnosis easier.

Comment: I'm torn between this solution and @dasblinkenlight's one. Can you elaborate on why this would keep things consistent?

Comment: When a user reports a problem, they report what they can see.  If the message that they see isn't reflected exactly in the logs, it can be difficult to diagnose problems. Depending on how you log exceptions, you could log both the short message _and_ the long message.

Comment: So I want to show them the `short` message but log the `long` message. I wanted to know how having an inner exception can help me with that as opposed to the way that I brought up originally?

Comment: @User5842 If you use something like `ex.ToString()` to log exceptions, having an inner exception logs _both_ without having to explicitly do so.  Logging the shorter message help you cross-reference to user feedback. If you _just_ log the long message it might be difficult to cross-reference user feedback with the logs.

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify for the purpose of learning. Using the above method, I can continue to use my `TraceException` method as usual but it will now log both exceptions for me, making it easier for a developer to find the root cause. On top of this, I am also able to throw the newer, more concise message to the user?

Comment: If `TraceException` logs the inner exception as well (which `Exception.ToString()` does by default) then yes. You can then choose to only show the outer exception message to the user (and have the option of showing the inner exception if appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a custom exception that carries both a long and a short message. Users who get the exception outside your library would access the short message through `Exception`'s `Message` property, while your `TraceException` method would access the long version through an additional property provided by your custom exception:

```
public class DetailedException : Exception {
    public string DetailedMessage { get; }
    public DetailedException(string longMessage, string shortMessage) : base(shortMessage) {
        DetailedMessage = longMessage;
    }
}
```

Inside `TraceException` method:

```
var message = (exception as DetailedException)?.DetailedMessage ?? exception.Message;
```

Comment: Just to provide some more context—I have 2 `finally` blocks where this exception will be thrown (for different reasons). So, using this method, I can, for example, create 2 different custom exceptions and then log them accordingly?

Comment: @User5842 You need only one custom exception class. Different `finally` blocks would create different instances of it, passing different detailed messages, which would be logged accordingly.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Also, did you mean to write `DetailedMessage = longMessage;` ?

Comment: @User5842 Yes, that was indeed the intention. Thanks!

Comment: When I create this new exception, would I still `throw` it as I originally was?

Comment: @User5842 Yes, apart from the exception tracing logic nothing else needs to change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153279/discussion-between-user-5842-and-dasblinkenlight).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the exception handler receive and process the longException and, as part of its function, throw the shortException?